# Why is cloc just one big file?

Tags: perl, cloc

I was just browsing through cloc's [GitHub page](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc/blob/master/cloc) when I noticed that the whole script consists of just one file with a whopping ~15000 lines of code. Do they patch multiple source files together or just use a really good ide? Having just one big source file seems a little inconvenient to me.

Comment: Seems like they have included CPAN modules inline to avoid dependencies

Comment: Seems like it was a design goal of theirs to make it as portable as possible, and concatenating all of their dependencies into a single file is definitely a way to do that. See the "Why Use cloc" section for details.

Answer (score 0):

Both Håkon Hægland and AKHolland are correct.  Regarding IDE, I just use vim.  (Folds in vim via `set foldmethod=marker` simplify code navigation; each subroutine appears to me as a single line.)